# Jquery: Reload Mainpage Using other page return value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
mainpage.php, 
loginModal.php, 
signInvalidate.php
```

I have a page has a button that when click a modal dialog box pop up, the content of the modal is from other page(loginModal.php) using jquery .load, so the content now of the modal is a login form which validates using jquery ajax that send information to signInvalidate.php. I have no problem on validation it still return error if it is error, but if it is correct information I want to reload the main page. How will I do that? or does Jquery .load accepting return TRUE value.

e.g.

signInvalidate.php

```
$result = $userFunction->checkLogin($useremail, @$password, @$remember, $gotUrl);

if($result == TRUE){

    return TRUE;

}
```

loginModal.php

```
success: function(msg){

    if(msg == TRUE){

        return true;

    }else{  

        $("#signInOutput").html(msg);

    }

}
```

mainpage.php

```
$('#previewOutput').load('modalLogin.php', function(){                        


});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably return a JSON object that has a known key (eg `status`) and value ( eg `success` ) for which you can check.

On PHP side, you can use (assuming 5.2+ ) instead of `return TRUE`:

```
print json_encode(array('status' => 'success' ));
```

if you need to return instead of print, you should obviously change that. On the Javascript side of things, you just JSON-decode that and process it :

```
success: function(data) {
  var state = $.parseJSON(data);
  if(state.status == 'success') {
     window.reload();
  }

}
```

I assume the above will need some tinkering, but it should serve as a good basis.

**Edit:** Fixed code.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the idea, i will try that but I have to study first JSON. . don't really know about that yet.

Comment: think of JSON as a very lightweight version of XML (lacking some features of XML that most people never use, and not as verbose). in the above example, you're encoding an associative array, so the JSON that will be sent is `{"status":"success"}` (an object).